# Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key Phonegap BUILD

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've been using the Google Maps plugin on Phonegap Build which worked fine until I recently tried to upload an updated version of the app to iTunes where I get: "Unexpected CFBundleExceutableKey.  The bundle at 'Payload/Test.app/GoogleMaps.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable.  If this bundle does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExceutable key from its Info.plist ..."

As referenced here:
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/612

disabling bitCode and removing the key seems to do the trick (I can't use the latest version yet because of a crash bug with adding GroundOverlay that hasn't been resolved).

So, the question is: how do you accomplish this on PGBuild?  I've tried editing the plugin.xml on a new fork using:

```
<config-file target="/GoogleMaps.bundle/Info.plist" parent="CFBundleExceutableKey" mode="delete">
    </config-file>
```

but a) I can't seem to alter the bundle Info.plist only the main app Info.plist and b) it doesn't seem possible to delete a key - only its value.

Comment: the plugin needs an update with latest google maps sdk, you can fork it and add the latest sdk yourself and install your version

Answer (score -1):

I noticed you have a typo in the parent parameter (it should be "CFBundleExecutable").
However, I am struggling with exactly the same issue but a different plugin. Was trying all various paths within the target parameter to eliminate the CFBundleExecutable key in PGB config.xml. I am getting the error message as it tries to eliminate the Executable at the App level (top-level Plist.info).
ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app' does not contain a bundle executable."